# Factoring a quadratic polynomial (absolute beginner level), are both answers correct?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I'm following video tutorials on factoring quadratic polynomials. So I'm given the polynomial:

$$x^2 + 3x - 10$$

And I'm given the task of finding the values of $a$ and $b$ in:

$$(x + a) (x + b)$$

Obviously the answer is:
$$(x + 5)(x - 2)$$

However the answer can be also:

$$(x - 2) (x + 5)$$

I just want to make sure if the question asks for the values of '$a$' and '$b$', then '$a$' can be either $5$ or $-2$, and '$b$' can be either $5$ or $-2$.

Therefore if a question asks what are the values of '$a$' and '$b$' both the following answers are correct:

Answer $1$
$a = -2$
$b = 5$
or
Answer $2$
$a = 5$
$b = -2$

I'm sure this is a completely obvious question, but I'm just a beginner in this.

Comment: Yes, the problem is symmetric for $a$ and $b$. So yes, the answers are $(a,b) = (-2,5)$ and $(a,b) = (5,-2)$.

Comment: They are both valid answers, since the order of the factors doesn't matter.

Comment: You teacher should have stated what context they want you to find $a$ and $b$, I have provided the answer below under the assumption that they meant the roots of the polynomial equation in $x$.

Comment: Even further so, they should have told you what the **domain** they would like $a$ and $b$ to be computed, and the corresponding **co-domain** of $x$ for which they wanted, the last part may not be appropriate terminology but I'm sure I will be corrected soon enough if that's the case.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your specific definitions. Unfortunately I don't have a teacher and am working by myself from Kahn Academy videos. I appreciate that there are many people here to give extra help.

Comment: Ok sure no problem You tube is way too bright for me so I just use it to listen to music, but if you want my advice, each time you learn a new word, look it up on google, find the Wikipedia page, and download the pdf document for it, and organise these in a library on your desktop.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody in either the comments or answers actually plugged the proposed "solutions" into the original equation and found that the possible answers are not, in fact, -2 and 5. It seems to me that -5 and +2 are better answers...

Comment: @twalberg Sorry? I've just used -2 and 5 and when I simplify I get x^2 - 3x - 10. We're looking to get x^2 + 3x - 10.  We get - 3x, not + 3x. Hope I'm right.

Comment: @Zebrafish The factorization `(x-2)(x+5)` is correct. But the values of `x` that are the roots of the entire equation are the values that make one (or more) of the factors equal to 0. In other words, the `(x-2)` factor is zero when `x = +2`, and the `(x+5)` factor is zero when `x = -5`. Those are the values for which `x^2 + 3x -10 = 0` (the `= 0` part was left off the original question, but is understood by the context).

Comment: @Zebrafish On the other hand, I guess if the question was really "find `a` and `b` in the factorization `(x+a)(x+b)`, then `-2` and `5` are probably correct, although they're the negatives of the roots of the equation, which is the more common definition of the solution of a quadratic...

Comment: @twalberg I'm sorry you've lost me, you must be talking about something way more advanced than I can understand. The factors given in my answer (x - 2) (x + 5), if you give x the value of 2 or -5 and substitute in, the left side of the equation still equals 0. I must be missing something else to your point.

Comment: @twalberb Also, (x - 5) (x + 2) is wrong, isn't it? as it results in x^2 - 3x - 10  ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.Yes, you are correct. Since $(x+5)(x-2) = (x-2)(x+5)  = x^2 + 3x-10$, we note that $a$ and $b$ may either take the values $(5,-2)$ or $(-2,5)$.

---

I would consider providing just one of the two solutions to be insufficient, since the question itself ask for the values of $a$ and $b$, but nowhere mentions that they are unique. However, any question saying "find the values of $a$ and $b$" is wrong with the word "the" : they are assuming uniqueness of $a$ and $b$, which is not the case.The question as quoted by you includes the word "the" , and this is misleading.

Comment: Yes, actually the statement "find 'the' values of a and b" is my invention. It's just from watching the videos that that's what it seemed the question was telling me to do. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I should add : Khan academy is a good source, but don't depend on only one source : when you find something wrong/fishy, try to use more sources to confirm it. With this in mind, it is good you asked this question. Also : are you in preparation for some exam, and hence doing these questions, or are you tallying this with something you are learning in some course currently?

Answer (score 3):

For [**commutative property**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of product we have that

$$(x + 5)(x - 2)=(x - 2)(x + 5)$$

note that also

$$(-x + 2)(-x - 5)$$

is a correct factorization.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

$$(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$$

and by identification with $x^2+3x-10$,

$$\begin{cases}a+b=3,\\ab=-10.\end{cases}$$

This is a non-linear system of equations, and given commutativity of addition and multiplication, it is clear that if $(u,v)$ is a solution, so is $(v,u)$.

---

Now one may wonder if more than two solutions could exist. As $a=0$ cannot be a solution, we can write

$$3a=(a+b)a=a^2+ab=a^2-10$$

which is the original equation (with a sign reversal)

$$a^2-3a-10=0.$$

To be able to conclude, you must invoke the fundamental theorem of algebra, which implies that a quadratic equation cannot have more than two roots.

So there are exactly these two solutions: $a=-2,b=5$ and $a=5,b=-2$.